# Is the Robocop universe the same as the Terminator universe?

Tags: the-terminator-series, robocop, robocop-1987

I know that there are comics and video-games with crossovers between the two franchises, but in canonical reference, do they really co-exist?

[image: Robocop Versus Terminator comic]

[image: Robocop Versus Terminator game]

Comment: What crossovers?

Comment: @Izkata - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop_Versus_The_Terminator_(comics)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - nice edits, you just beat me to it! (I was typing exactly the same).

Comment: The owners of the intellectual property can decide what is real and what is not... so the correct answer might be "which is more profitable for them".

Comment: They're both documentaries of our world so obviously the answer is yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest answer is no. Although the world of Terminator isn't mutually exclusive from the world of Robocop (as evidenced by the [comic](http://multiversitycomics.com/columns/crossed-out-crossovers-robocop-vs-terminator/) + [video-game](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ondd-dD0fa0/UwQLY8-OXFI/AAAAAAAAGdU/oGq15SDJ620/s1600/robocop+vs+terminator+portable+snes.gif) crossovers), there is no canon reason to assume that one is set in the same world as the other.

On top of that, the film Robocop seems to be [set between November 2043 and February 2044](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43112/when-in-which-year-is-robocop-set) whereas "[Judgement Day](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Judgment_Day)" in the first couple of Terminator films occurs sometime between June 2005 and October 2011.

---

On a more positive note, the original [Robocop film trailer had the Terminator theme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41085) running in the background so there's been some *slight* crossover, if only because the film shared a distributor...

Comment: "On top of that, the film Robocop seems to be set between November 2043 and February 2044" -- well, only if you take a joke about Sylvester Stallone's death in the novelization by Ed Naha (who was not involved in the production of the original film, according to imdb) as canon. I don't think it's the usual custom in other franchises that novelizations are treated as canon, except possibly in cases where they were done by the writers or other creators of the films, or in close consultation with them.

Comment: Well, the new film is set in 2028; http://www.movietickets.com/moviedetails/mid/133379/fc/1/language/9

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not in the same universe.

Some reasons:

1. There are no technological connections between the two universes - In the Robocop universe, advanced cybernetics were decades into the future. In Terminator 3, which is set in 2004, the DoD is shown having the autonomous air and land drones that Skynet uses it its various future settings to hunt down and destroy humanity. This places the Terminator “past” decades ahead of the Robocop “future” in technological capabilities.
2. None of the narrative in the films link the universes - If Skynet were possible fifty years earlier than the setting of Robocop ( roughly the decade of the 2040s) then much of technology would already exist and it would be seen as being as impressive as it was in Robocop.Also none of the film reference the others during their respective films.
3. They are creations of completely different set of writers,producers and directors - The Terminator was created by James Cameron and writer Bill Wisher. They were inspired by an idea Cameron had. The Robocop universe was created by Edward Neumeier with assistance of writer Michael Miner. Since they had no creative collaboration inside of the film franchises it can be safely presumed that no such link between the projects existed until it conceived later after their individual box office successes.

Answer (score -2):

One big difference is - Skynet appears to be entirely machine driven, as in AI gone nasty on it's creators.

In Robocop, it was evil corporations run by humans calling the shots.